# How to test lib files in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I understand the benefit of putting classes, modules, etc. in the **lib** folder in Rails, but I haven't been able to find a *clean* way of testing these files.  For the most part, it seems like unit tests would be the logical approach.

I guess my question is: *What is the "rails way" for testing lib files?*

Comment: your code in `lib` can do all kinds of things.. ways of testing background workers and, say, some amazon-connecting stuff can be pretty different

Comment: @neutrino Let's just say it's a generic class with a few methods that perform some text manipulations.  Not much different than a full-fledged Model, but it's not saving anything into the database.

Comment: Any reason you don't just make a unit test for them?  Unit tests don't have to just be for ActiveRecord models.

Comment: I guess that's what I'm asking ... is that the most common way?  I'm fine going down that route, but if there's a previously established convention, I'd prefer to follow that.

Answer (score 1):

Your lib directory is not automatically loaded by rails.

You can use `ActiveSupport::Dependencies` to override `const_missing`. Basically rails will try to load your constants when it boots, if they are undefined or not in memory it will look at your load paths.

If you have a file like `my_class.rb`, rails expects it to be `MyClass`.

The beauty of this is if you have some stuff in your `lib` directory, you don't have to require it with a relative path you can just say `require 'something'`, instead of `require 'lib/something'`.